# VBA: Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. It is not copying to range

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code:

```
Sub RunFilter()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCritRow As Long, LastResultRow As Long
Sheet1.Range("C31:AH365").ClearContents 'Clear Existing Results
With Sheet2
    If Sheet1.Range("L27").Value = "Enter name." Then LastCritRow = 2 'Determine Last Criteria Row
    LastRow = .Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row of Data
    .Range("A2:AF" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("AI2:BN" & LastCritRow), CopyToRange:=.Range("BQ2:CV2"), Unique:=False
    LastResultRow = .Range("BQ999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Results Row
    If LastResultRow < 2 Then GoTo NoResults
    Sheet1.Range("C31:AH" & LastResultRow + 29).Value = .Range("BQ2:CV" & LastResultRow).Value 'Copy Over Results
NoResults:
End With
End Sub
```

I am getting an error on this line:

```
.Range("A1:AF" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("AI1:BN" & LastCritRow), CopyToRange:=.Range("BQ1:CV1"), Unique:=False
```

I googled possible issues, like the names being off or not correctly specifying the ranges. So I checked the ranges in my advanced tab to what I placed in the code and they were off by 1 so I updated them. I am still getting the error.

Edit to a comment: This is what is in cell L27 when I have not entered the specifications for filtering. This is assigned to a button:

```
Sub ClearFilter()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheet2.Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row of Data
Sheet1.Range("C31:AH" & LastRow + 29).Value = Sheet2.Range("A2:AF" & LastRow).Value 'Bring Data Over
Sheet1.Range("L27").Value = Sheet1.Range("AN31").Value 'Copy Over Default Text
Sheet2.Range("AI2:BN2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Here: ```If Sheet1.Range("L27").Value = "Enter name." Then LastCritRow = 2```

Comment: Well what if `Sheet1.Range("L27").Value` doesn't equal "Enter Name"? What should the value of `LastCritRow` be then?

Comment: I don't want it to be anything else. It should always be 2.

Comment: Is there an `else/end if`?

Comment: No, I do not have an else/end if.

Comment: This means you have **no** criteria at all. You simply copy pasting the whole range without any filter. Why bother at all with `AdvancedFilter`? There is a discrepancy between your full code snippet and the single line. I guess you want: `CriteriaRange:=.Range("AI1:BN2")`

Comment: Okay, the tips y'all are giving me are at least getting it to run now, but like @JvdV said, it is now just copying the entire thing not what I want to filter.

Comment: Pls, note the **discrepancy** between your code snippet and the single line: It should (without seeing your data) be: `.Range("A1:AF" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("AI1:BN2"), CopyToRange:=.Range("BQ2"), Unique:=False`

Comment: I used your code and it's not working. When I run the advanced filter through the data tab, it will filter the data and copy to range the ones that include what was filter. When I try to do the macro, it just copies everything.

Comment: *"I don't want it to be anything else. It should always be 2"*. Then why have an `If` statement? Just set that variable to `2`.

Comment: I had tried just setting it to 2, I still cannot get it to do what I am trying to get it to do.

Comment: Seems to me you clear the entire range on Sheet1 that includes L27; then you do an "If" on Sheet1, L27 = "Enter Name" with nothing that would indicate there would be anything but an empty cell for L27.